# Need help embedding an if-else statement in an if-else statement to cause a page redirect

Tags: php

Ok I am trying to make a customized shortcode for my wordpress site that I can put on multiple pages to detect if a user is logged on or not, then redirect them to a registration/login page if they are not. However I want to set it to check to display their username if their first name is unavailable upon login verification. Everything looks correct to me but I'm still relatively new at this so any assistance is greatly appreciate in advance.

I was looking in to if.. elseif.. statements to handle this issue but it just doesn't really add up to me when I try to type it out, it seems like that is just for conducting a sequence of checks not for embedding an ifelse statement in an already existing ifelse statement.

Here's the code:

```
//first name retrieval shortcode
function firstname_retrieval () {
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  if (empty($current_user->user_firstname)) {
    echo 'Hello, ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
  }
  else {
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';    
  }
} else {
  header( 'Location: https://www.industrialmaintnenace.org/login/' );
}
add_shortcode ( 'userinfo', 'firstname_retrieval' );
```

Comment: Not sure if the missing indentation was on accident or if that's what your code actually looks like, but if your code didn't have indentation, the properly indented version may make the workflow a bit more obvious. The body of each part of an if/else statement can have pretty much whatever code you want in it. If it's more if/else statements, those will be evaluated by the processor too.

Comment: if-else statements can be nested as you have it in the example. One thing to note about the `header()` redirects is that they will only work if called before anything is rendered on page. This code needs to appear before the opening `<html>` tag without even a single space before it.

Comment: I do not get what your question is. You say the code looks correct, but does it work or not? If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: @Cy So have you actually tried your code?  Or are you just assuming that it wouldn't work?  If the former, what was the result and how does that differ from what you want?

Comment: Hi yes I had tried my code and kept getting a syntax error but it seems I missed a closing bracket for the function. Once I added that in the code works smoothly. I'm not sure about the header() issue, I have seen people saying that online which is why I was thinking that might be causing the issue but the code is running perfectly now so I'm going to have to look in to that a bit more.

Comment: @CyLewisHoward If this was just a case of a missing bracket, then you question should be closed as Off Topic (Typo)

Comment: Patrick I don't disagree. Sorry this is my first post to this site but doesn't an Admin handle that sort of thing? It could definitely help some future reader about the flexibility of if-else statements. I searched for about an hour for someone stating what Joshua Dwire did in a couple seconds. Helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By spacing your indents accordingly, you get the following PHP code:

```
// First name retrieval shortcode
function firstname_retrieval () 
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        if(empty($current_user->user_firstname)) 
        {
            echo 'Hello, ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header( 'Location: https://www.industrialmaintnenace.org/login/' );
    }

add_shortcode ( 'userinfo', 'firstname_retrieval' );
```

As you can see there is no closing brace on your function, whether that has been missed in your copy or not, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you! I need to format my code better so I can catch mistakes like this I like how wide open your style is. I appreciate it, what a simple mistake.

Comment: I'm going to go through my files and space everything out better I appreciate you Jim for real thank you.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up about missing a closing brace, show me a coder that says they haven't and I'll show you a liar.